# Webcam driver doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, drivers, webcam, logitech-webcam

Trying to install a Logitech C270 onto a system running Win10 Enterprise. It's supposed to be plug-and-play; it's not acting that way. Runs the generic MS driver instead of anything specific; and Windows throws an error message saying the driver is not completely installed. Logitech has a file (LogiCameraSettings_2.12.8) which we have downloaded and run. We've even deleted the driver from Device Manager and run the Logitech file. Camera still says it's running off a generic driver that is not completely installed. End user is unable to use the on-screen controls to PTZ the camera; the primary reason the camera was bought was to be able to zoom out onto two or more participants in a web meeting. (The internal web cam has no zoom capability; the EU has to push the computer more than an arm's length away from the participants to see them both in the view; but then no one can operate the computer.) Logitech support was less than helpful; in the first place, when I mentioned zooming the camera, the tech thought I was trying to use the camera in a Zoom meeting. If anyone knows how to make this work, I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: When you download the driver, and manually look at the .inf file, is the camera in question list within the .inf file?  I also presume that Windows 10 is explicitly called out as being supported by Logitech.

Comment: Certainly is. The page on Logi's web site indicates a number of upgrades for Win10. The file is an .exe that is not a self-extracting archive; ergo, no apparent .inf. Just ran the file on my own machine to verify that.

Comment: You will have to extract the contents of the .exe into a folder to examine the .inf file more than likely.

Comment: Much to my surprise, given that it behaved like an executable and not a self-extracting archive, I actually can see inside the exe. No inf file at all. Not one. Not even drilling down through all the subfolders. Whole boatload of dlls; no inf.

Comment: You have checked the optional updates within Windows Update.  Device drivers are installed through Windows Update not Device Manager on Windows 10 version 2004 and newer.  You can obviously still install drivers with an executable.

Comment: Our operation is running 1909 at the moment.